# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): Django form

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm trying to subscribe an email account into a newsletter using Django, when I try to click the Go button I get the error Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):

Here is the views.py method:

```
def newsletterSubscribe(request):
try:
    form = NewsletterUserSignUpForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if NewsletterUser.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            messages.warning(request, _('Alerta! El correo ingresado ya se encuentra suscrito.'),
                             'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible')
        else:
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Correo agregado con exito!'),
                             'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')

            subject = _('Gracias por unirse a nuestro boletín')
            message = _("""Bienvenido al boletín de ADA Robotics. Si deseas no estar suscrito visita: 
                        https://127.0.0.1:8000/unsubscribed""")
            msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg['From'] = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['To'] = instance.email
            msg['Subject'] = subject
            part = MIMEText(message, 'plain')
            msg.attach(part)

            mail = smtplib.SMTP(settings.EMAIL_HOST, settings.EMAIL_PORT, timeout=20)
            mail.starttls()

            """
                template = get_template("myapp/sample_template.html")
                context = Context(context_data)
                body_html = template.render(context_data)
                body_text = strip_tags(body_html)
                part1 = MIMEText(body_text, 'plain')
                part2 = MIMEText(body_html, 'html')
                msg.attach(part1)
                msg.attach(part2)
            """

            emailto = [instance.email]
            mail.login(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
            mail.sendmail(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, emailto, msg.as_string())
            mail.quit()

            """from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = [instance.email]

                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=to_email, message=message, fail_silently=False)"""

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    template = 'subscribed.html'
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return render(request, template, context)
except Exception as ex:
    return render(request, '404.html')
```

Here is the template code:

```
<form id="newsletterForm" action="{% url "newsletterSubscribe" %}" method="POST" class="mr-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="input-group input-group-rounded">
                                <input class="form-control form-control-sm bg-light" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="newsletterEmail" type="text">
                                <span class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-light text-color-dark" type="submit"><strong>GO!</strong></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
path('contact/', contact, name="contact"),
path('subscribed/', newsletterSubscribe, name="newsletterSubscribe"),
```

I have the middleware added into my settings file and also migrate the database to have the tables already created.

What I'm trying to do is a form for a newsletter and is located in the base.html of the templates so it can be available in all the other pages around the web app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the context which includes the form object into the render function. You're form *is* loading because it's all html, but the `{% csrf_token %}` isn't loading because you haven't passed the form object into the template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

```
render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

yours would be:

```
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: I added the context like:

`return render(request, template, context)`

But I still get the same error, also added the other views the same context just in case

Comment: in your code above you changed it to `content` instead of `context`. Otherwise you may just want to structure your view as in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view
instead of the try/ except pattern.